# Expanding query table rows based on another table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list/table in sharepoint that I am trying to create a project ghantt for, imported to excel with query. I was planning on using the stacked bar chart in excel to do this. The issue im having is that in this chart there are multiple columns with dates for each specific task (when its done). To be able to create a ghantt for each project as overall + specific subtasks i need to expand each row (project) for each subtask to be able to make the stacked bar chart. Since this query table will change in size i cant think of a dynamic way of doing this. I essentially need to dynamically merge two tables of data and Subtask table then i can vlookup / index to pull the right dates into the right task and make my poor man's ghantt.

Thank you so much for taking a look at this,

Here's some sample data:

[image]

Subtasks table: Overall, engineering, Surface Land, Construction, able to add items dynamically is bonus

This is what I would like the outcome to look like:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Latest as it’s through Office 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with a little tidy up of your column names and a few steps in Power Query.

Having your starting column names of the format "[task] Start" and "[task] End" will help later:

[image]

First step is to use 'Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range' to create a query on this table.

When the Power Query Editor opens, select the columns containing the dates, then use 'Transform>Any Column>Unpivot columns>Unpivot only selected columns':

[image]

That will give you a new view of the data with columns "Attribute" and "Value".

[image]

Next, we need to use the "Pivot Column" command. But to do that, we need to have a column that only contains something indicating whether the current row is a start or an end date. So, use 'Add Column>General>Custom Column' and configure it like this:

[image]

Here's that formula for the StartEnd column:

```
if Text.PositionOf([Attribute],"Start") > 0 then
Text.Range([Attribute],Text.PositionOf([Attribute],"Start"))
else
if Text.PositionOf([Attribute],"End") > 0 then
Text.Range([Attribute],Text.PositionOf([Attribute],"End"))
else "Neither start nor end"
```

You might want to convert the data type of the "Value" column to Date rather than Date/Time. Next, we need a column that just holds the name of the task. So use 'Add Column>General>Custom Column' and configure it like this:

[image]

Here's the formula for the Task column:

```
Text.Trim(Text.Replace([Attribute],[StartEnd],""))
```

(almost there!)

Next, we can right-click the Attribute column and choose "Remove". Then, select the StartEnd column and use 'Transform>Any Column>Pivot Column', like this:

[image]

After completing the Pivot, use Home>Close & Load, and you'll have your properly pivoted query:

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is very comprehensive, thank you so much. Some of it may be a tad over my head, but as i started doing this i noticed that once i unpivot the columns im looking to isolate (my query actually has way more than my sample above) it basically gives me two columns Attribute and Value being the date. I can even at this point work with this as i can make a Concatenated column so i have a table of A1- Test 1 TOTO Date  B2 - Date which works great.

Comment: I need a way to automatically change the NULL to N/A or zero maybe to retain that item's position. As as far as dynamically adjusting the tasks I think i know enough now that i could just adjust this procedure again if they add more details to our projects.

Comment: For empty cells in the source, try right click and replace values before the unpivot operation. Glad it was of use. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer if it's helped you get where you need to be.